What battery do I buy for the Minolta Hi-Matic 7
I just bought this camera and I don’t know what type of battery to buy for it. I’ve looked it up and found results for the 7s and 7ii but none for just the plain ol' 7. What battery would you suggest?

The ever-useful cameramanuals.org website has the manual for this camera at: https://www.cameramanuals.org/minolta_pdf/minolta_hi-matic_7.pdf - however the PDF is incomplete, missing the last few pages, and unfortunately that's where the battery information is specified.

Is it possible that the 7s battery will work?  This website says the only real difference between the 7 and 7s is including a hotshoe and better metering. (Not posting this as an answer because I am just guessing)

Also, it seems that the battery is only used for the in-camera metering. So if you are using an external meter, then maybe you don't actually need a battery?

And the original battery was a mercury based 1.35v one, so you are unlikely to find anything like that now.   In searching for "Minolta Hi-Matic 7 battery" I've seen several references to various people suggesting 1.5v batteries (such as PX625 alkaline cell), and that you get acceptable exposures with that.  But again, this is all hearsay to me.

And see also Does the Minolta Hi Matic 7 need batteries to function?
